# inserting into database using restSQL, via xml from url

Tags: android, xml, database, psql

I am currently making an app for android and use restSQL to access my database.

There is no problem using SELECT queries so I guess the setup is correct.

The problem is when I want to insert into my table from the url and the attributes should be variable. I don't know how to make the xml such that you can insert specific data.

**example:**
database/path/to/xml/?attribute1=1&attribute2=2

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(DEFAULT,attribute1 "attri1",attribute2 "attri2")
```

The DEFAULT comes from the key is a serial and then I want a xml which can insert into my table with the two attributes I am given in the url.

The error it returns is:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ""attri1""
```

The "" works fine when it is a select statement. I have been looking at the documentation for restSQL but can find a xml document with an insert statement.

Hope you can help : )

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp,

You should try this-->

`INSERT INTO table (attribute1,attribute2) VALUES ("attri1", "attri2")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer : )

This does give the following error:
ERROR: column "attri1" does not exist

If the "attri1" is replaced by a number it works. 

Think the problem is that it is restSQL since the query works fine if it is given directly to the database.